# How to elevate an already running session within its own code

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory, powershell-4.0, elevation

I'm writting a PowerShell script that configures some things in Active Directory.

I need to run it as a specific user in order to get the right permissions for the process, currently i'm running the .ps1 file through a .bat file, so I can choose "run as a different user" or "run as administrator".

What I'm tryng to achieve is that inside the script I will ask the user for the right credentials, and then elevate the session to run with the inputed user creds.

I've tried using this within my code:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "TestDomain\Me"
```

But it just opens an empty PS Session while the current session keeps running.

I want to use this code to get the creds from the user:

```
$msg = "Enter your Domain Admin Credentials"; 
$creds = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential($caption,$msg,"","")
$rstusername = $creds.username;    
$rstpassword = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().password
```

and then use `$rstusername` AND `$rstpassword`, to change the running script credentials.

Is that even possible?

Comment: _I'm writting a PowerShell script that configures some things in active directory._ So you are using the Active Directory module? Normaly all of the AD commandlets have a `-Credential` parameter that can be used for this.

Comment: can you give me an example ? syntax ?

Comment: For example: `$cred = Get-Credential; New-AdUser $username -Path $adpath -Credential $cred` With `$username` and `$path` set somewhere else in your code. See e.g. `help -full New-ADUser`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run cmdlets in another user's context when they allow providing explicit credentials (parameter `-Credential`), or by running them via `Invoke-Command` (which has a `-Credential` parameter).

Example:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock {
  # commands here
} -Credential $cred
```

Or you could use something like this to re-run the entire script with different credentials:

```
if (-not $env:USERNAME -eq 'Me') {
  $cred  = Get-Credential
  $param = '-NoLogo', '-File', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
  Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList $param -Credential $cred
  exit $LASTEXITCODE
}

# other code here
```

Elevating the current session (or "moving" it to a different context) is not possible.