# PowerShell remoting session variable isn't working

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run a loop using `New-PSSession` and running as administrator, but I am getting an error.

```
foreach ($c in $targets) {
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $c -Credential cred
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {gci C:\temp} -RunAsAdministrator
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Comment: Well, yes. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) for the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet you'll see that it doesn't have a parameter set with both the `-Session` and the `-RunAsAdministrator` parameter.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370223/how-to-elevate-an-already-running-session-within-its-own-code) could help

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because the `-Session` parameter can't be used at the same time as the `-RunAsAdministrator` parameter.

Comment: I also get the same error when trying to run the Invoke-Command cmdlet with the ComputerName parameter.  What is the correct format to use RunAsAdministrator?  I am in a UAC environment, so I think it's necessary.

Comment: I think you can only use it when executing a command locally.